# как преобразовать индексы из DataFrame в данные?

Tags: python, pandas

В местном магазине решили добавить анализ данных и каждый чек представлять в виде DataFrame.

Прайс-лист уже сформирован в виде объекта Series, где индексами являются названия, а значениями — цены.

Напишите функцию, cheque, которая принимает прайс-лист и список покупок в виде неопределённого количества именованных параметров (ключ — название товара, значение — количество).

Функция должна вернуть объект DataFrame со столбцами:

- наименование продукта (product);
- цена за единицу (price);
- количество (number);
- итоговая цена (cost).
  Строки чека должны быть отсортированы по названию продуктов в лексикографическом порядке.

Пример

```txt
Ввод
products = ['bread', 'milk', 'soda', 'cream']
prices = [37, 58, 99, 72]
price_list = pd.Series(prices, products)
result = cheque(price_list, soda=3, milk=2, cream=1)
print(result)
Вывод
product  price  number  cost
0   cream     72       1    72
1    milk     58       2   116
2    soda     99       3   297
```

мой код:

```
import pandas as pd


products = ['bread', 'milk', 'soda', 'cream']
prices = [37, 58, 99, 72]
price_list = pd.Series(prices, products)

def cheque(price_list, **kwargs):   
    d = {'price':price_list,  'number': kwargs }
    price = pd.DataFrame(d)
    price['cost'] = price['number'] * price['price']
    return price

print(cheque(price_list, soda=3, milk=2, cream=1))
```

Результат:

```
       price  number   cost
bread     37     NaN    NaN
cream     72     1.0   72.0
milk      58     2.0  116.0
soda      99     3.0  297.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно добавить `.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'product'})`, где `.reset_index()` "переносит" индекс в столбец, а `.rename()` переименовывает этот столбец

```
return price.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'product'})
```

```
  product  price  number   cost
0   bread     37     NaN    NaN
1   cream     72     1.0   72.0
2    milk     58     2.0  116.0
3    soda     99     3.0  297.0
```

Comment: Низкий поклон тебе. а еще вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в результате таблицы отображались только именованные аргументы указанные при вызове функции cheque(). В моем варианте отображается NaN

Comment: добавьте `.dropna()`